# Google Artifact Registry (GAR) summary of space used by images

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, containers, gcloud, google-artifact-registry

I'd like to be able to identify how much space is used by all images with a certain tag. The idea for this, is to be able to tell which dev team is consuming "too much" space.

Each dev team, will use a particular container TAG that will help identify them.

I tried using gcloud cli for this matter but I was unable to find a way to achieve such thing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the moment, you can only determine the size of Google Artifact Registry per image. You can determine the size in **two** ways:

- Through the [Repositories page](https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts?_ga=2.243691840.435217333.1678113127-418012167.1677791049&_gac=1.157992776.1678114337.CjwKCAiAu5agBhBzEiwAdiR5tOc_Cnlb0U-DrhSslOTmzPu-XjBWIqIx9MFULFozouAjtxD6AUVERRoCglYQAvD_BwE)
- Or by entering the code below through gcloud CLI:

  ```
  gcloud artifacts docker images list
  ```

You may check this documentation on [listing images](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/manage-images#listing_images) for additional information.

You may also want to file this as a feature request through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). There's no specific ETA on this but you can check its progress by following the ticket once it's created.

Comment: Thank you Robert! Request (271896075) created. I thought maybe there was some "big query" or similar magic that could be applied already.